# How to customize temperature scales in Outlook 2013 in its calendar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, calendar

Is there an option somewhere in Outlook 2013 to customize temperature scales from Fahrenheit to Celsius and wind speed measurement from mph to kph?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the units (Fahrenheit/Celsius and MPH/Kmph) used for the weather in the Calendar Options (Go to File - Options). 
The last option under "Calendar" category is Weather.

- Selecting Celsius will display the temperature in Celsius and speed in Kmph and
- Selecting Fahrenheit will display the temperature in Fahrenheit and speed in Mph.